# Is it necessary to update to https when using http in UnityWebRequest for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I’m trying to test my app in iPhone, but Xcode throws this error:

> You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.”

I'm using UnityWebRequest with URL "http://..." (to download a JSON file), I already added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in true, but it doesn’t work. Is it really necessary to update to https, or are there other ways to do it if I don't have https?

The problem is that from Unity Editor it works, but it's not working from an iOS device.

Comment: `Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` they are telling you this is currently done so you don't have to do this. If you are not caring about the security you can simply use `https:// ...` and use a custom CertificateHandler which overrides [CertificateHandler.ValidateCertificate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CertificateHandler.ValidateCertificate.html) to simply always return `true`

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now my problem is it works sometimes not always.
Do you have any idea about this?